# Android - App Update Manifest Version Code and Name

Tags: android

**my Android Manifest File :**

my existing Version Code = 1

also

my existing Version Number = 1

I want to update my App and I know that have to change my Version Number e.g. to 1.1 but what does the **Version Code** mean?

- Should it stay at 1?

Or do i have to change it also? Maybe be to 2? oder anything else?

Thx for ur help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Version Code is important. It indicates a release number. 1= first release, 2 = second release etc of your APK.

Version number is a display version that shows major minor release versions.

> **android:versionCode** — An integer value that represents the version of
>   the application code, relative to other versions. The value is an
>   integer so that other applications can programmatically evaluate it,
>   for example to check an upgrade or downgrade relationship. You can set
>   the value to any integer you want, however you should make sure that
>   each successive release of your application uses a greater value. The
>   system does not enforce this behavior, but increasing the value with
>   successive releases is normative. Typically, you would release the
>   first version of your application with versionCode set to 1, then
>   monotonically increase the value with each release, regardless whether
>   the release constitutes a major or minor release. This means that the
>   android:versionCode value does not necessarily have a strong
>   resemblance to the application release version that is visible to the
>   user (see android:versionName, below). Applications and publishing
>   services should not display this version value to users.
>
> **android:versionName** — A string value that represents the release
>   version of the application code, as it should be shown to users. The
>   value is a string so that you can describe the application version as
>   a .. string, or as any other type of absolute or
>   relative version identifier. As with android:versionCode, the system
>   does not use this value for any internal purpose, other than to enable
>   applications to display it to users. Publishing services may also
>   extract the android:versionName value for display to users.

Source:
http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/versioning.html

Comment: Great! This answer I wanted to know :) THX a Lot! greetings!

Comment: Seems like the answer but where in the manifest? These are attributes on some element in the manifest and that is not identified here.

Answer (score 3):

> but what does the Version Code mean?

It is how the OS, the marketplaces (Play Store, etc.), and other tools determine whether or not your APK represents an upgrade.

Quoting [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/versioning.html):

> Typically, you would release the first version of your application with `versionCode` set to 1, then monotonically increase the value with each release, regardless whether the release constitutes a major or minor release. This means that the `android:versionCode` value does not necessarily have a strong resemblance to the application release version that is visible to the user (see `android:versionName`, below).

If your app is already published with an `android:versionCode` of `1`, your next upgrade needs to have an `android:versionCode` higher than `1`.

Answer (score 2):

The `version code` is a code used not to presentation but for inner use.
for example, to update a new version to the google play - you'll have to increase it by 1 at least.
Another example - the Android application DB will get the onUpdate method pop if this version code is greater then the previous one.

Answer (score 0):

Each time you publish a new version to the Google Play, you have to increment your version code. So, here it will be 2.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

As it says on the official docs at http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/versioning.html:

> android:versionCode — An integer value that represents the version of
>   the application code, relative to other versions. The value is an
>   integer so that other applications can programmatically evaluate it.
>
> android:versionName — A string value that represents the release
>   version of the application code, as it should be shown to users. The
>   value is a string so that you can describe the application version as
>   a <major>.<minor.>point> string, or as any other type of absolute or
>   relative version identifier. As with android:versionCode, the system
>   does not use this value for any internal purpose

So I guess you should come with your own numbering scheme. For example, you could use 9 digit scheme, with 3 3-digit pieces for <major>.<minor.>point>. In this case, 1.1.0 would be 001001000, and then 1.1.1 would be 001001001 and so on. This guarantees that you can compare the number directly to know if a version is older or newer.